# How do i create a div with dojo create?

Tags: html, dojo

i want to generate the divNodes0 div from this example via dojo create (including the h1 and ul):

```
<body class="mobile">
    <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.View" id="mobileView">
        <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="divNodes01" scrollDir="v" style="background-color: #d0d0d0;">
            <h1 dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading" fixed="top" id="h1Nodes01"></h1>
            <ul id="ulNodes01" dojoType="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
[...]
</body>
```

i tried it this way (without sucess):

```
var mobileView = document.getElementById("mobileView");
dojo.create("div",{
            id: "divNodes0",
            dojoType: "dojox.mobile.ScrollableView",
            scrollDir: "v",
            style: "background-color: #d0d0d0"
            },
            mobileView,"first");


var mainNodeDiv = document.getElementById("divNodes0");
dojo.create("h1",{
            id: "h1Nodes0",
            dojoType: "dojox.mobile.Heading",
            back: "zurŸck",
            moveTo: "divNodes0",
            fixed: "top",
            label: "Knoten&uuml;bersicht"
            },
            mainNodeDiv,"first");

    dojo.create("ul",{
            id: "ulNodes0",
            dojoType: "dojox.mobile.RoundRectList"
            },
            mainNodeDiv);
```

greets Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to look up nodes by Id, you generally want to use `dojo.byId('someId')`

The third parameter to `dojo.create` can be either a domNode (like you are using) or an id of a dom node:  `dojo.create('h1',{},'divNodes0','first')`

Based on your usage of the `dojoType` attribute it seems like you want to use "widgets" rather than dom nodes.  Widgets are generally a template of domnodes with built in styling and event handling that are easily reusable.  Instantiating and placing widgets is simple:

```
var heading = new dojox.mobile.Heading({
  id: "h1Nodes0",
  dojoType: "dojox.mobile.Heading",
  back: "zurŸck",
  moveTo: "divNodes0",
  fixed: "top",
  label: "Knoten&uuml;bersicht"
});
heading.placeAt('divNodes0','first');
```